# Send mail *without* mail queue in Django

Tags: django, email

Im using django_yubin to send mails via its mail queue.

However, there are a few instances where I want to send the mail immediately *without* putting it on the queue.

For example, when a user registers or resets their password. Or certain admin emails.

I tried using Django's built in email system by

from django.core.mail import send_mail as send_mail_core

and then using the send_mail_core() function.

This didnt work - looks like the send_mail in django.core.mail gets overridden by yubin

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you even try to use `send_mail_core` if you can select the mail backend inside of [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mail) function

```
def send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list,
          fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None,
          connection=None, html_message=None):
```

> connection: The optional email backend to use to send the mail. If
>   unspecified, an instance of the default backend will be used. See the
>   documentation on [Email backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#topic-email-backends) for more details.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could do that!